# After forking, are global objects reconstructed? python multiprocessing

Tags: python, database, multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing pool to process a list of usernames. Each username requires some database operations.

In this paradigm where I have some globals in my parent process, say

```
DB = Database()

def function(username):
  pass

def main()
  with Pool(2) as pool:
    res=pool.map(function, range(10))
```

In my example, I included a print statement and it shows that it is initialized twice. I would expect the DB object to follow copy-on-write semantics and since I haven't done anything with it, I don't expect it to construct.

Is there a better way to handle shared database connections across multiple processes?

Comment: Because of reference-counts being updated everywhere, I think almost nothing can really be CoW between processes in CPython like you want. Using multiple threads within one process may be better than multiprocessing, especially since database applications are often IO-bound. I think some database vendors have APIs that make sure that different connections/cursors behave nicely from different threads.

Comment: @Dennis one notable exception are things like `numpy.ndarray` objects, which can leverage COW if you require read-only access. Similarly, `array.array` objects

Comment: Good point @juanpa.arrivillage

Comment: "is there a better way?" find a way to leverage all the parallelism tools already built into your database. That may mean running a manager process which holds the DB cursors, and clients make requests via named pipes or local sockets, or possibly the DB software is already multi-threading aware. I would look for memory-mapping options to ensure only what's needed is pulled from disk into ram.

Comment: I see - so is it safe to say that when python calls fork() every global variable is reconstructed? Assuming that this wasn't the case (like if we were in C++) and forks followed CoW semantics, then would the object still be constructed? I'm interested because pickle is just a compressor for object representation, but it can't retain / transfer network authentication. Assuming that db connections are pickle-able (idk if this is true) I don't think I can just pass authentication from 1 process to another via pickle. At what point, in C++, would the object be explicitly constructed?